# What is the use for a table that cannot contain nor reference foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

[MariaDB's documentation about partitioning](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/partitioning-limitations/) lists one of its limitation as,

> - A partitioned table cannot contain, or be referenced by, foreign keys.

In the context of a DBMS, what could be the use of a table with such restrictions? I don't think I have ever seen a design of a DB without tables being related via foreign keys, so I am wondering if I understand correctly MariaDB's limitations (the situation seems similar with MySQL).

Comment: Perhaps no need for fk's for log tables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cause of the limitation is that internally each partition is an InnoDB table of its own, so foreign key lookups would need to be spread out across all of these, instead of being a single 1:1 lookup.

The InnoDB engine is not even aware that these are not independent tables of just the same structure, but that they form a partitioned table on the SQL level. At the same time foreign key checks are still implemented within the engine, thus they don't work yet for partitioned tables.

The reason why you might still want to use partitioned tables, and sacrifice server side referential integrity checks for that is simple: performance tradeoffs.

On the MariaDB side we have a feature request for foreign key support, and it is currently targeted for the upcoming 10.5 release series:

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12483

But it's not 100% sure yet that it will happen in time for 10.5.

On the MySQL side there is:

https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=148

but its from 2009 already without any visible progress since then as far as I can tell.

PS: I've been on projects where FKs were only in place during development and testing, but not on the actual production DB, assuming that ans possible FK violations would already have shown up and been fixed during dev/testing ... again this was done for performance reasons, as FK checks take their time ...

Comment: I see FKs for partitioning as low priority.  (See my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase jarlh, 'Perhaps no need for `PARTITIONing`.'

Seriously, `PARTITION` does not intrinsically provide *any* performance gain.  The main case where partitioning is useful, namely deleting "old" data, may be useful for a log table.  This is where you have daily (or weekly, etc) partitions, and use `DROP PARTITION` as a *much* less invasive way of deleting data older than a week (or month or year, etc).  And then do a `REORGANIZE PARTITION` to create a partition for 'tomorrow' (etc).

`SELECT` is not sped up by partitioning except in a few rare scenarios.  One is when you need a "two dimensional" index such as "find the nearest" in a geographical sense.  (But `SPATIAL` is a viable contender for such a use case.)

More on partitioning (or not):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: Any sources supporting your claims?

Comment: @Sebi2020 - No credible sources, just years of experience.  The MySQL reference manual is especially devoid of info -- It lists what _can_ be done, but _whether it is worth_ doing.